# Adding new view to OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers

I am adding new views for my map with a `switcher` from https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers `Dark ("Dark Matter")` to be exactly. as attribution is needed i am import from `OSM` but when i exchange to dark map i get this error
`cartodb-basemaps-%7Bs%7D.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/10/295/545.png:1 GET https://cartodb-basemaps-%7Bs%7D.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/10/295/545.png net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

[image: error]

Here is my code:

```
import OSM,{ATTRIBUTION} from 'ol/source/OSM';

const dark = new TileLayer({
  title:'Dark Map',
  visible:false,
  type:'base',
  source: new XYZ({
    url:'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
  }),
  attribution:['Map tiles by Carto, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL.',ATTRIBUTION]

});
```

I am following : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html

Comment: @MrXsquared  just updated

Comment: See the note about `{s}` at the top of https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers  The server appears to support subdomains a, b, c and d, so in OpenLayers you can use `url:'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-d}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'`